# Find cell header to copy to

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following issue: I am trying to automate the copying of data to a certain column indicated by the header, but it errors out: "Object variable or with block not set". What I am trying to do is to add the row header to an one dimensional array, find the range that matches the searched mth_exp_PM and store it in another variable, preferably a set range (cell ?) to use further to copy.

What am I doing wrong ? If this solution is not OK, what is the best/easier solution to copy to the column based on the row header ?

Thank you!

```
dim i as long
dim cell, cell_adr as range
dim arr() as string
dim mth_exp_PM as string 'this value is taken from a different workbook and it matches one row header value

i = 0
For Each cell In Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)).Cells
    ReDim Preserve arr(i)
    arr(i) = cell
    If arr(i) = mth_exp_PM Then
        cell_adr = arr(i)
        Debug.Print cell_adr
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `IF` condition instead of

```
cell_adr = arr(i)
```

use

```
Set cell_adr = cell
```

`cell` is a range and will be assigned to `cell_adr` which again is a range. To get the address of the cell use `Debug.Print cell_adr.Address` for `Debug.Print cell_adr`.

If you are not using `arr` anywhere else in your code you can remove it. In the code below I've commented lines that are not required if your don't have to use array.

```
Sub Demo()
    'Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range, cell_adr As Range 'declare cell as Range
    'Dim arr() As String
    Dim mth_exp_PM As String 'this value is taken from a different workbook and it matches one row header value

    'i = 0
    For Each cell In Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)).Cells
        'ReDim Preserve arr(i)
        'arr(i) = cell
        'If arr(i) = mth_exp_PM Then
        If cell = mth_exp_PM Then
            Set cell_adr = cell
            Debug.Print cell_adr.Address
        End If
        'i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One line correction needed, as below, majorly (`arr(i) = cell.value`)

bellow presented your code revised correction.

```
dim i as long
dim cell, cell_adr as range
dim arr() as string
dim mth_exp_PM as string 'this value is taken from a different workbook and it matches one row header value

i = 0
For Each cell In Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)).Cells
    ReDim Preserve arr(i)
    arr(i) = cell.value 'Do correct here!
    If arr(i) = mth_exp_PM Then
        Set cell_adr = cell 'Correct here!
        Debug.Print cell_adr.Address 'and Correct here
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```